# How can I run an SSRS report as the current Windows User?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report which will list information depending on which employee runs the report.

I want the information to be 100% unique to each employee therefore, I want the report to automatically determine who the employee is based on their windows login.

In SQL, I can do this by executing the following:

```
 SELECT HOST_NAME() AS HostName, SUSER_NAME() LoggedInUser
```

This returns the following data:

```
+--------------+--------------------+
|   HostName   |    LoggedInUser    |
+--------------+--------------------+
| MCC-ASUSN53S | MCCOSKERS\PGunston |
+--------------+--------------------+
```

The above works in SSRS too however, it returns details based on the SQL Server, NOT the machine which the report is being accessed from.

Is there a way to achieve what I am attempting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To retrieve the user accessing the report, you can use [`User!UserID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255216.aspx) variable from the `User` collection.